# Focus floating system windows with keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard

The windows I'm talking about are the system administrator password request popups, the wireless network web sign-in popup, and other system request dialogs, such as "Application was downloaded from the Internet" confirmations. Often when these popups appear for me there is no focus on the input/buttons. I need to remove my hands from the keyboard and mouse over to them.

These popups do not appear in the application switcher, and seem to be immune to these focus-grabbing keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>
- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

I have seen one solution that involved turning on OS X's VoiceOver utility with <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>,<kbd>F2</kbd>. I'd prefer not to have this turned on, since in my regular work hours I use <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+F-keys in my IDE.

I would post pictures, but my reputation isn't high enough yet.

UPDATE: I do, in fact, already have the option set in System Preferences to allow keyboard  navigation in all control windows.

Comment: VoiceOver doesn't have to be Control-Option-F2; it's Command-F5 by default.

Answer (score 3):

If you enable full keyboard access in System Preferences, you can press tab to select the buttons.

[image]
[image]

I don't know how to focus the windows though. They can't be selected with ⌃F4 or ^F6. I was going to suggest [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/), but it doesn't show them either.

This is a bit of a hack, but you could [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with p in {"SecurityAgent", "CoreServicesUIAgent", "loginwindow"}
        if exists process p then
            tell process p
                if windows is not {} then
                    set frontmost to true
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Password dialogs are shown by SecurityAgent, Gatekeeper and quarantine dialogs by CoreServicesUIAgent, and the force quit window by loginwindow.

Comment: I do, in fact, have this option already checked. The issue occurs if I happen to be switching applications as the popup appears, causing it to lose focus but remain on top of all other windows.

Comment: Tried your AppleScript as an extension to Alfred (a launcher that can assign global hotkeys). It still refuses to focus `networksetup is trying to modify your system configuration` dialogs :(

Comment: It works for me at least after running `networksetup -setcomputername a` in Terminal.